# CakePHP 2.0 Table helper

Tags: css, cakephp-2.0

Is there any table helper or plugin or component for CakePHP 2.0+ ?

if yes, can anyone please help me by providing information where I can get some useful tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

The [HtmlHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3atableHeaders) has some methods that help with building a table.
There is also an (old) [TableHelper](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/scottsanders/2009/05/08/table-helper-1)

Comment: thank u. I am looking for a complete CakePHP 2.0 Table helper like Cakephp 1.3. cheers.

Comment: Looking at the list of helpers at http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1357/Core-Helpers it seems there is no TableHelper in CakePHP 1.3.

Comment: sorry, i mean third party helper.